# API for getting past 10 years of P&L data for a particular NSE/BSE stock

Tags: programming, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to get past 10 years P&L data for a bunch of Indian companies, but can't seem to find a good API to do so. I have tried yfinance, Alpha Vantage, IEX cloud and a few others. I tried web scraping certain websites but they always have some sort of rate limiter. Does anyone know of a good API that I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried out a bunch of these links. The only working one I could find was fmp, but the free version only supports US markets. Is there an alternative?

Comment: You may want to try asking in the [Open Data Forum](http://opendata.stackexchange.com/)